# tmpfs - files still present after unmounting

Tags: linux, tmpfs

I am learning about `tmpfs`. The [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/tmpfs.5.html) for `tmpfs` says -

> The tmpfs facility allows the creation of filesystems whose contents
>   reside in virtual memory.

and -

> If a tmpfs filesystem is unmounted, its contents are discarded
>          (lost).

But I can see the files even after unmounting -

```
mediumone@ubuntu:~$ mkdir tmpfsdir
mediumone@ubuntu:~$ cd tmpfsdir/

mediumone@ubuntu:~/tmpfsdir$ sudo mount -t tmpfs tmpfs ~/tmpfsdir/

mediumone@ubuntu:~/tmpfsdir$ findmnt
TARGET                                SOURCE         FSTYPE              OPTIONS
/                                     /dev/sda1      ext4                rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro
├─/sys                                sysfs          sysfs               rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime
│ ├─/sys/kernel/security              securityfs     securityfs          rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime
│ ├─/sys/fs/cgroup                    tmpfs          tmpfs               ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755
..snip
├─/snap/gnome-3-28-1804/116           /dev/loop15    squashfs            ro,nodev,relatime
└─/home/mediumone/tmpfsdir            tmpfs          tmpfs               rw,relatime

mediumone@ubuntu:~/tmpfsdir$ echo "hello world" >> hello
mediumone@ubuntu:~/tmpfsdir$ ls -l
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 mediumone mediumone 12 Feb 17 02:15 hello

mediumone@ubuntu:~/tmpfsdir$ sudo umount -l ~/tmpfsdir/

mediumone@ubuntu:~/tmpfsdir$ findmnt
TARGET                                SOURCE         FSTYPE              OPTIONS
/                                     /dev/sda1      ext4                rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro
├─/sys                                sysfs          sysfs               rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime
│ ├─/sys/kernel/security              securityfs     securityfs          rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime
│ ├─/sys/fs/cgroup                    tmpfs          tmpfs               ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755
..snip
└─/snap/gnome-3-28-1804/116           /dev/loop15    squashfs            ro,nodev,relatime

mediumone@ubuntu:~/tmpfsdir$ ls -l
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 mediumone mediumone 12 Feb 17 02:15 hello
mediumone@ubuntu:~/tmpfsdir$ cat hello 
hello world
mediumone@ubuntu:~/tmpfsdir$
```

I tried with `sudo umount -f ~/tmpfsdir/` too and I got the same result.

Can someone explain what is going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mounted over your current directory. Your shell will continue to use the original directory instead of the mounted one until you `cd` back to it. Other commands will also inherit the original directory:

```
% mkdir foo
% cd foo
~/foo
% df -h .
Filesystem                  Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/ubuntu-vg-root  1.8T   77G  1.7T   5% /
% sudo mount  -t tmpfs tmpfs ~/foo
% df -h .
Filesystem                  Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/ubuntu-vg-root  1.8T   77G  1.7T   5% /
```

A fresh access to the directory will use the mounted one, though:

```
% df -h . ~/foo
Filesystem                  Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/ubuntu-vg-root  1.8T   77G  1.7T   5% /
tmpfs                       3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /home/muru/foo
```

And if you `cd` to it again:

```
% cd .
% df -h . ~/foo
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /home/muru/foo
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /home/muru/foo
```

Answer (score 2):

When `cd` to `tmpfsdir` first time, your shell's working directory is on existing filesystem. `mount` does not change your working directory and the new file is created on the underlying filesystem where your working directory is, not on `tmpfs` filesystem.

Change directories after mounting, and you will get the result you expected.